# Complexity analyisis & recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to find complexity for the below two recursive functions but have no clue how to approach complexity analysis for recursive functions

To find all possible Subsets

```
def subsetsHelper(self, nums, index, path, res):
    if path is None:
        return
    res.add(path)
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        self.subsetsHelper(nums, i + 1, path + [nums[i]], res)

def subsetsWithDup(self, nums):
    res = []
    self.subsetsHelper(nums, 0, [], res)
    return res
```

To find all possible Permutations

```
def permuteHelper(self, nums, index, path, res):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        res.append(path)

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        copy = list(nums)
        val = copy.pop(i)
        self.permuteHelper(copy, i, [val] + path, res)

def permute(self, nums):
    res = []
    self.permuteHelper(nums, 0,[], res)
    return res
```

Also, what is the recurrence relation of the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity relation of the first algorithm is `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1`, if the length of `nums` is `n`. Now try to solve this by expanding the equation.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1
T(n) = (T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1) + 1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1 
T(n) = 2T(n-2) + 2T(n-3) + ... + 2T(1) + 2
T(n) = 2(T(n-3) + T(n-4) + ... + T(1) + 1) + 2T(n-3)... + 2T(1) + 2  
T(n) = 2^2 T(n-3) + 2^2 T(n-4) + ... + 2^2T(1) + 2^2
```

Hence, `T(n) = O(2^n)`.

As mentioned in comment, for the second algorithm as you have a copy in each iteration and recall the function the same array except one of the. Hence, `T(n) = n * T(n-1) + n^2` (`n^2` is for `n` copy of the array  with size `n`). Using the expansion, we will have:

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1) + n^2
T(n) = n * ((n-1) * T(n-2) + (n-1)^2) + n^2
T(n) = n*(n-1) T(n-2) + n * (n-1)^2 + n^2
T(n) = n*(n-1) ((n-2) * T(n-3) + (n-2)^2) + n * (n-1)^2 + n^2
T(n) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)T(n-3) + n*(n-1)*(n-2)^2 + n * (n-1)^2 + n^2
```

Hence `T(n) = O((n + 1)!)`.

Comment: In the first algorithm, in each iteration of that loop,we increment `i`, so iteration in the next recursive call decreases by 1 each time. But in the second algorithm in each iteration of that loop, the length remains constant. So recurrence should me something like `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(n^2)` which approximately is `O(n!)` (not sure about solution to this recurrence).